# Как такое правильно написать?

Tags: php

В общем, я думаю каждый играл на серверах SAMP и каждый видел, что у каждого игрока свой ID. То есть, допустим на сервере 700 игроков и если я зайду, то у меня должен быть ID 701, если кто-то выйдет, у меня данный ID должен остаться, айди меняется при каждого заходи на сервер. Так вот, как мне такое реализовать?

Моя идея была такая, когда игрок заходит на сервер, я добавляю его в массив, ключ - это и есть ID. Но, если скажем игрок какое-то вышел, то я по факту буду уже не 701, а 700 в массиве. Как мне правильно реализовать ID для каждого игрока?

Comment: регистрируйте пользователей в Базе Данных, это быстро, бесплатно, и каждому пользователю будет выдаваться id без вашего участия (автоинкремент)

Comment: Это сильная нагрузка, я так делать не буду :)

Comment: Если вы про то, чтобы у каждого пользователя был свой айди постоянно, не, не хочу так :)

Comment: Если массив будет массивом объектов, то ничто не мешает внутри объекта сделать свойство id. Оно будет прибавляться на основе id  последнего объекта в массиве.

Comment: можно пожалуйста поподробнее?

Comment: Новичок на бота похож... возможно в вопросе перепутано понятие ID и номер сессии какой-то...

Comment: Смысле бот? Причём тут номер сессии? Речь идёт именно о айди, он порядковый.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/DQhU4Rxrj9jYe5cw8 - это по твоему сессия? Не знаешь - не пиши

Answer (score 0):

```
class Server {
    public $users = [];
    
    public function enter(User $user) 
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;
    }
    public function leave(User $user) 
    {
        $this->users = array_filter($this->users, function($serverUser) use ($user) {
            return $serverUser !== $user;
        });
    }
    
    public function showOnlineUsers() 
    {
        foreach($this->users as $onlineID => $user) {
            echo "User name: ".$user->name .PHP_EOL;                  
            echo "User server ID: ".$onlineID.PHP_EOL;               
            echo "User real ID: ".$user->uuid .PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;             
        }
    }
}
class User {
    public $uuid;
    public $name;
    
    public function __construct(string $name) 
    {
        $this->uuid = uniqid();
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
$server = new Server;

$user = new User('User 1');
$server->enter($user);

$user2 = new User('User 2');
$server->enter($user2);

$user3 = new User('User 3');
$server->enter($user3);

$server->showOnlineUsers();

// вывод:
// User name: User 1
// User sever ID: 0
// User real ID: 635cf675b9c48

// User name: User 2
// User sever ID: 1
// User real ID: 635cf675b9c51

// User name: User 3
// User sever ID: 2
// User real ID: 635cf675b9c52

$server->leave($user2);

$server->showOnlineUsers();

// вывод:
// User name: User 1
// User sever ID: 0
// User real ID: 635cf675b9c48

// User name: User 3
// User sever ID: 2
// User real ID: 635cf675b9c52

// Т.е. User 2 вышел, но у User 3 остался его ID на сервере такой, какой и был до выхода User 2
```

Comment: а можно это все реализовать в одном классе? Нечего же не будет?)

Comment: Можно хоть в 1 строку всё написать, ничего же не будет?... По-хорошему, ещё отдельный класс нужен для добавления/удаления игроков на сервер. Почитайте про SOLID, DRY, KISS и прочие принципы и соблюдайте их